# PHP Newbie. Prepared statement doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I've started learning mysqli prepared statements technique, and stuck with these lines:

```
include 'config.php';
$location=$_SESSION['cl'];
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM locations WHERE loc LIKE ?");
$sql -> bind_param('s',$location);
$sql -> execute();
$sql->store_result();
$sql -> bind_results($results);
while($sql->fetch()){
echo $results;
}
```

Can anybody explain what could be wrong?

Comment: did you started session? `session_start()`?

Comment: did you tried to `echo $location` and see what is there?

Comment: @Akam Yap, it contains a string.

Comment: ok then try to print `$sql->error`

Comment: Well, it doesn't show anything :/

Comment: Try with `$sql -> bind_results($results);` inside of your while loop just before `echo $results`.

Comment: your bind_param is binding to `'s'` but you are using `?`, could you try changing the `'s'` to integer `1`.

Answer (score 2):

Your **BIGGEST and foremost** problem is **lack of error reporting**.

It spoils not only this particular problem but your whole experience with PHP.
Every time when something goes wrong, PHP will tell you - what happened and whom to blame. Only if you let it. And you always should.

On a live site you have to peek into error logs, so, settings have to be

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',0);
ini_set('log_errors',1);
```

while on a local development server it's all right to make errors on screen:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

The moment you see the error message the problem solved. (Only one though. another will be followed)

Also add the following line in your `config.php` **before** connect:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

to be notified of all the errors from mysql side

Also note that you shouldn't use LIKE for the string comparison and your query have to be

```
SELECT loc FROM locations WHERE loc = ?
```

Comment: I've tried to add error reporting to my code, but still it doesn't show any errors. I used LIKE, because I wanna search in my database for user inputed text.

Comment: Well, try it again, harder.